# Tailwind - How to add 2 linear gradients background on same element?

Tags: css, background, background-image, tailwind-css, linear-gradients

Is it possible in Tailwind to add two linear backgrounds to one element?
Here is the CSS code which works:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f8fafb 50%, #161616 50%),
      linear-gradient(to right, #161616 50%, #f8fafb 50%);
```

I have tried to add it two times like this:

```
className = "bg-gradient-to-r from-white to-black bg-gradient-to-r from-black to-white";
```

And a few combinations with [], but it is not working.
Any help is welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

Ending color
set the ending color of a gradient using the to-{color} utilities.

```
<div class="bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500 ..."></div>
```